# Android moving strip like Sliding Drawer

Tags: java, android, slider, slideshow

I try to realise following view in androind application.

In my programm i want to divide the main activity between two. 
Now it does't work propertly. I want, that the line between two 
windows in activity is moveable and the line can divide the whole screen in 
different proportion. Not only to show whole one window or another.

Image for understanding [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-M1_M1vsiywdE5zLXhqV1FnNzA/edit?usp=sharing)

My programm looks like:
MainActivity.java

```
    package dva.checkin;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        OnMyLocationChangeListener {

    private boolean firstStart = true;
    private GoogleMap map;
    private LinearLayout listView;
    private LinearLayout mapView;
    private View divider;
    private float touchActionDownX;
    private float touchActionDownY;

    private ListView dataList;
    private void initCustomList() {

        dataList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.locations_list);

        dataList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    final int position, long id) {
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initCustomList();


        listView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        mapView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.map_view);

        divider = (View) findViewById(R.id.divider);
        divider.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
                    touchActionDownX = event.getRawX();
                    touchActionDownY = event.getRawY();
                    Log.i("DOWN", "" + touchActionDownX + " ; "
                            + touchActionDownY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                    // Log.i("test","Move");

                    float touchActionMoveX = event.getRawX();
                    float touchActionMoveY = event.getRawY();

                    Log.i("MOVE", "down " + touchActionDownX + " ; "
                            + touchActionDownY);
                    Log.i("MOVE", "curr " + touchActionMoveX + " ; "
                            + touchActionMoveY);

                    if (touchActionMoveX < touchActionDownX) {
                        Log.i("MOVE UP", ""
                                + (touchActionMoveX - touchActionDownX));
                        // UP
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpar = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mpar = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mapView
                                .getLayoutParams();

                        if (lpar.weight > 0.2) {
                            lpar.weight -= 0.1;
                            mpar.weight += 0.1;
                        }

                        listView.setLayoutParams(lpar);
                        mapView.setLayoutParams(mpar);
                    } else if (touchActionMoveX >= touchActionDownX) {
                        // DOWN
                        Log.i("MOVE DOWN", ""
                                + (touchActionDownX - touchActionMoveX));
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lpar = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView
                                .getLayoutParams();
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams mpar = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mapView
                                .getLayoutParams();

                        if (mpar.weight > 0.2) {
                            mpar.weight -= 0.1;
                            lpar.weight += 0.1;
                        }

                        listView.setLayoutParams(lpar);
                        mapView.setLayoutParams(mpar);
                    }

                    touchActionDownX = touchActionMoveX;
                    touchActionDownY = touchActionMoveY;

                    break;
                }
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    divider.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00FF00"));
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

        if (firstStart) {
            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location
                            .getLongitude())).zoom(18).build();

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            firstStart = false;
        }

    }

}
```

than activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/list_view" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkin"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/checkin" 
        android:onClick="checkIn"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/locations_list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
 <View android:id="@+id/divider"
           android:layout_height="15dip" 
           android:background="#00ff00"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"  />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/map_view">


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="dva.checkin"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="dva.checkin.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="dva.checkin.CheckinDetailsActivity"
            android:parentActivityName="dva.checkin.MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="dva.checkin.MainActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".DisplayImageActivity"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for suggestions!

Comment: I do not understand your question. Do you want a slider that will show portions of your layout as you slide up or down? Also, please mark your questions as answered please.

Comment: How does the current code work or does it work? Affecting layout params on touch move could cause serious hiccups on performance.